# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40804) with this library (version 0x40801) Aborted core dumped

Tags: 13.04, qt, libraries

> ... Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40804) with this library (version 0x40801) Aborted core dumped

The Problem occurs with 64-Bit Ubuntu 13.04 when starting k3b, ebook-viewer ..., gnome-classic (no effects).

Sometimes the border of all open windows and terminals disappear and I have to reboot.

I didn't find out which libraries are conflicting ...

Kind Regards Justus Gadient

```
xxx@yyy:~/Desktop$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib::/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64:/opt/intel/opencl/lib64:/opt/intel/opencl/libmic
```

> open("x86_64/libQtXml.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   read(3, Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40804) with this library (version 0x40801)
>   stat("/usr/local/DigiaQtCommercialSDK/Desktop/481/gcc-64/plugins", 0x7fff8cf68e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
ldd
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa83fe000)
libk3bdevice.so.6 => /usr/lib/libk3bdevice.so.6 (0x00007f30ea2ac000)
libk3blib.so.6 => /usr/lib/libk3blib.so.6 (0x00007f30e9efb000)
libkcddb.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkcddb.so.4 (0x00007f30e9c9a000)
libkfile.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkfile.so.4 (0x00007f30e99f5000)
libkio.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkio.so.5 (0x00007f30e9558000)
libknotifyconfig.so.4 => /usr/lib/libknotifyconfig.so.4 (0x00007f30e9345000)
libkde3support.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkde3support.so.4 (0x00007f30e9050000)
libsolid.so.4 => /usr/lib/libsolid.so.4 (0x00007f30e8d64000)
libQtWebKit.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4 (0x00007f30e6a16000)
libkcmutils.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkcmutils.so.4 (0x00007f30e67d8000)
libQt3Support.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt3Support.so.4 (0x00007f30e6306000)
libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4 (0x00007f30e60c3000)
libkdeui.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5 (0x00007f30e5a7f000)
libkdecore.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkdecore.so.5 (0x00007f30e55bf000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /opt/intel/opencl/lib64/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f30e50ca000)
libQtDBus.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtDBus.so.4 (0x00007f30e4e4f000)
libQtGui.so.4 => /opt/intel/opencl/lib64/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f30e40e7000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f30e3de3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f30e3a1a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f30e3715000)
libsamplerate.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamplerate.so.0 (0x00007f30e33a8000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f30e31a4000)
libdvdread.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdvdread.so.4 (0x00007f30e2f87000)
libmusicbrainz5.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmusicbrainz5.so.0 (0x00007f30e2cfe000)
libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f30e29bf000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f30e27a9000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f30e259e000)
libnepomuk.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomuk.so.4 (0x00007f30e22ce000)
libQtSvg.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4 (0x00007f30e2078000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f30e1d3d000)
libstreamanalyzer.so.0 => /usr/lib/libstreamanalyzer.so.0 (0x00007f30e1ac5000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f30e18bd000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f30e16b7000)
libphonon.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libphonon.so.4 (0x00007f30e1449000)
libkparts.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkparts.so.4 (0x00007f30e11f5000)
libkpty.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkpty.so.4 (0x00007f30e0feb000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f30e0dda000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f30e0bc2000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f30e0971000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f30e074b000)
libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f30e050e000)
libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f30e0302000)
libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f30e00f0000)
libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f30dfecb000)
libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f30dfcaf000)
libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f30dfa5b000)
libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f30df774000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30df525000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f30df1c2000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30deec5000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f30dec19000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f30de9df000)
libQtOpenGL.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4 (0x00007f30de6e0000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f30de501000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f30de2e4000)
libQtSql.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSql.so.4 (0x00007f30de0a4000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f30dde9c000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f30ddc7f000)
libattica.so.0.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattica.so.0.4 (0x00007f30dd9c7000)
libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 (0x00007f30dd794000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f30dd58d000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f30dd37d000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f30dd15b000)
libdlrestrictions.so.1 => /usr/lib/libdlrestrictions.so.1 (0x00007f30dcf56000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30dcd54000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f30dcb4c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f30ea4e3000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f30dc907000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f30dc66a000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f30dc457000)
libneon-gnutls.so.27 => /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27 (0x00007f30dc230000)
libsoprano.so.4 => /usr/lib/libsoprano.so.4 (0x00007f30dbf49000)
libsopranoclient.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsopranoclient.so.1 (0x00007f30dbcfb000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f30dbadd000)
libstreams.so.0 => /usr/lib/libstreams.so.0 (0x00007f30db8a6000)
libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f30db65e000)
libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 (0x00007f30db459000)
libnepomukutils.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomukutils.so.4 (0x00007f30db21f000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f30db01c000)
libutempter.so.0 => /usr/lib/libutempter.so.0 (0x00007f30dae19000)
liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f30dab9a000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30da996000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f30da78d000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f30da54e000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f30da325000)
libatiuki.so.1 => /usr/lib/libatiuki.so.1 (0x00007f30da207000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f30da002000)
libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26 (0x00007f30d9d45000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f30d9b07000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f30d9902000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f30d96fc000)
libjson.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0 (0x00007f30d94f3000)
libpulsecommon-3.0.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-3.0.so (0x00007f30d928f000)
libnepomukquery.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomukquery.so.4 (0x00007f30d9049000)
libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x00007f30d8dca000)
libtasn1.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3 (0x00007f30d8bb9000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f30d89a5000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f30d86d6000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f30d84ad000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f30d82a9000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f30d80a0000)
libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f30d7e96000)
libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f30d7c30000)
libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f30d7a29000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f30d7825000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f30d7620000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f30d7406000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f30d71ec000)
libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f30d6f9f000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f30d6ad0000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f30d68a3000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f30d669b000)
```

Comment: "Cannot mix incompatible" says everything. You can only mix compatible ingredients, no?

Comment: Meanwhile I upgraded to 13.10 but the Problem still exists on my new Ultrabook. (No longer on my old Desktop with similar 64-Bit configuration, 
since yesterday some qt... upgrades dropped in, still don't know whether this is the cause)


Unfortunately I urgently need an offline epub reader on my Ultrabook, so I use Adobe digital edition in a VirtualBox Windows for the moment, sorry for that ;-) 


Kind Regards

Justus Gadient

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the cause:
Once upon a time I created a Timetracker with qtcreator. Still compiles and runs fine 
in the IDE but the binary on the command line does not run:

xxx@xxx:... qt/TimeTracker/QTTimeTracker$ ./QTTimeTracker 
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40804) with this library (version 0x40801)
Aborted (core dumped)

xxx@xxx:... qt/TimeTracker/QTTimeTracker$ ldd QTTimeTracker
...

```
libQtGui.so.4 => /opt/intel/opencl/lib64/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f742f370000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /opt/intel/opencl/lib64/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f742ee7b000)
                      =====>häääh
```

...

Obviously the HD4000 opencl driver installs QTlibs?? 
Moving them to "/opt/intel/opencl/lib64/whatdotheqtlibshere/" seems to solve my problems 
(QTTimetracker and fbreader do not crash any more, heissa)

Comment: Exactly the problem I had! Thanks a bunch for posting this.

Comment: On Antergos a removal of  qt5-styleplugins (`sudo pacman -R qt5-styleplugins`) solved this issue.